# A level Integration question.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

1a) Prove that $$e^x\operatorname{sech} x\equiv\frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}$$

b) Find $$\frac{d}{dx}[\arcsin(\tanh x)]$$ 
Simplify your answer as far as possible.

c) Hence, or otherwise, solve $$\int e^x\arcsin(\tanh x)dx$$

I did parts a and b but then got stuck on part c. Can someone please explain how I go about solving this? 
Thanks.

BTW, for part b I got an answer of $\operatorname{sech}x$.

Comment: So how could you use part b to do part c? It must be integration by parts!

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

First use integration by parts (along with your knowledge found b).

Second use part a to rewrite the resulting integral.

Third set $u=e^{2x}$ and evaluate.

And of course, $+C$ must be remembered!